# What's wrong with the prime number generator?

Tags: c++, primes

I wrote a code. The goal was to find the prime numbers up to 1000. It compiles and runs, but it seems that the table is blank at the end. What is the reason for this? How do I fix it? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;



int primes[20];
bool prime;
int main()
{
    int i;
for(i=2;i<=1000;i++){
prime=true;
int ii;
   for (ii=1;ii<=sizeof(primes);ii++){
       if (i/ii==floor(i/ii)){
                             prime=false;
                             }
       }
       if (prime==true){
       primes[sizeof(primes+1)]=i;
   }         
}
for (i=1;i<=20;i++){
cout << primes[i] << endl;
system("pause");
}
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is homework, here are some hints: what do you think that `sizeof` does ? What does this line do: `primes[sizeof(primes+1)]=i;` ? (Oh, and you might also want to fix your formatting - too hard to read the code otherwise.)

Comment: primes[sizeof(primes+1)]=i ... ouch. Learning a little about array allocation and the meaning of sizeof would be an excellent start.

Comment: 1:Not homework 2:Should I use floats instead?

Comment: Why c++? Are you trying to learn c++ this way? You should start understanding basic then. If you just want to have something working quickly, another language would probably do a better job.

Comment: Not really addressing your question (it is answered below already), a good way to speed up the program is to use the list of primes in the second for-loop as the divisors (not going always from 1 to 1k)

Comment: You should learn how to use vector for dynamically-growing data-sets. vector, by the way, is just one option for such a data-set, you can also use list or deque. deque allows fast insertion at either end and is also generally better for large sets or when you want to guarantee your objects to remain intact and not get reallocated, and list is even more flexible when you want to erase or insert in the middle or move elements from the middle to one of the ends or vice versa, but does not support random-access.

Answer (score 0):

This comparison:

```
i/ii==floor(i/ii)
```

is always true, because you are doing integer division. Both `i` and `ii` are integers, so C++ does an integer division when calculating `i/ii`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do integer division instead do modulus and check whether the remainder is 0.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `vector<int>` instead of plain array to handle the array allocation and size housekeeping for you, and with a bit different syntax you may achieve approximately what you want.

2) Test `i/ii==floor(i/ii)` is bad. Use either floating point division, or (better) modulus operator.

3) `if (prime==true)` - this is another typical construct showing lack of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The way I generate all numbers up to N is as follows:

```
std::vector< int > lowestFactors( N+1, 1 );
for( int n = 2; n * n <= N; ++n )
{
    if( lowestFactors[ n ] != 1 )
        continue; // our number is not prime

    for( int m = n; m * n <= N; ++m )
    {
        if( lowestFactors[ m ] != 1 && lowestFactors[m] != n )
          continue;

        lowestFactors[m * n ] = n;
    }
}
```

each cell will now contain in lowestFactors:
- 1 if it is prime
- its lowest factor if not prime.
- 0 and 1 don't count.

You can also initialise all of lowestFactors with their own values, and can size it N-1 subtracting 2 when you access a number